# C# Get line of multiline String starting with specific word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a multiline string, say

```
abcde   my first line
fghij   my second line
klmno   my third line
```

All of this is one String, but what I want to do now is to get the content (substring) of this string which is starting with a specific word, for example "fghij". So if I do a method and pass "fghij" to it, it should return me "fghij   my second line" in that case.

The following I tried, but it does not work, unfortunately m.Success is always false:

```
String getLineBySubstring(String myInput, String mySubstring)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(myInput, "^(" + mySubstring + "*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Console.WriteLine("getLineBySubstring operation: " + m.Success);
        if (m.Success == true)
        {
            return m.Groups[0].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return "NaN";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` operator is currently quantifying the last letter in `mySubstring`. You need to precede the operator with `.` to eat up the rest of the characters on the given line. No need for grouping either.

```
Match m = Regex.Match(myInput, "^" + mySubstring + ".*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (m.Success) {
   // return m.Value
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/U7xdmS)

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just change the `*` char to `[^\r\n]+`

```
Match m = Regex.Match(myInput, "^(" + mySubstring + "[^\n\r]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

`[^\r\n]+` will match any character, but `\r` and `\n`, which are used to mark a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add line ending `$` to your regex. Also `*` concatenated to `mySubstring` specifies repeat of the last symbol in `mySubstring`, you should have `.*` to catch all the possible ones.

```
Regex.Match(myInput, "^(" + mySubstring + ".*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check that string starts with some substring, then you should avoid Regex. Just split whole string to lines and check each line with StartsWith.

```
String getLineBySubstring(String myInput, String mySubstring)
    {
        string[] lines = myInput.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var line in lines)
            if (line.StartsWith(mySubstring))
                return line;
        return "NaN";            
    }
```

Comment: Could you add more reasoning to your advice? (I'm interested also what are the benefits)

Comment: Just simplicity. Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

Comment: Regex is just an instrument for text processing, so while you are processing text (retrieving some expressions as in current question), you'd better use tools which were designed for such a task, instead of manual strings splitting. (I can't say that your code is worse for current task, but advice of avoiding regex is rather categorical)

Comment: It is good to have alternative ways to solve a problem. I remember having a exercise at university doing text processing tasks with Regex explicitly not allowed.